# How to pass image to a default image to database as byte array in C# WCF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

I'm developing a system that use Entity Framework Code First technology for data base creation and, I need to store an image file to the database using this. I have done this but have a problem when there is no image file selected.

So I need to know, how to pass a default image file to the db if no image selected, (let's think i have no default image in my hard drive, so by default code need to generate the image file any how).

I'm using layered architecture,

1.Entity Layer - for code first db creation

2.Data Access Layer - for accessing db and all the db related methods are here

3.Business Logic layer - for connecting interface with data access layer

4.Presentation Layer - for interface designing

codes on 1,2,3 has completed as follows,

-------Entity-------

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BisCare.BMS.Entity
{
    public class RentingGood
    {
        public RentingGood() { }

        public Guid RentingGoodId { get; set; }
        public string RentingGoodName { get; set; }
        public bool RentingGoodStatus { get; set; }
        public byte[] RentingGoodImage { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<RentingGoodsStock> RentingGoodsStocks { get; set; }
    }
}
```

------- Data access-------

```
public bool AddRentingGoodData(string name, string catName, byte[] image)
        {
            try
            {
                Guid catGuid = new Guid();

                using (EntityModel model = new EntityModel())
                {
                    var CatId = from b in model.Categories
                                where b.CategoryName == catName
                                select b;

                    foreach (var x in CatId)
                    {
                        catGuid = x.CategoryId;
                    }

                    Category category = model.Categories.Find(catGuid);

                    RentingGood newGood = new RentingGood() { RentingGoodId = Guid.NewGuid(), RentingGoodName = name, Category = category, RentingGoodStatus = true,RentingGoodImage = image };

                    model.RentingGoods.Add(newGood);
                    model.SaveChanges();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply generate a standard image at runtime:

```
Bitmap standardImage = new Bitmap(200, 200);
Graphics standardGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(standardImage);
int red = 0;
int white = 10;
while (white <= 200)
{
    standardGraphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 0, red, 200, 10);
    standardGraphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, white, 200, 10);
    red += 20;
    white += 20;
}

//This will be your byte array
byte[] result = ConvertImageToByteArray(standardImage);
```

This example above draws a red white flag. More examples and tutorials about drawing in C# can be foun [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383872%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

I made the method `ConvertImageToByteArray` to convert the image to a byte array which can be saved in the database which looks like this:

```
public byte[] ConvertImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image image)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

It would be better if you could save the generated byte array somewhere. Then you don't need to regenerate the image everytime someone don't upload an image.

Comment: Thank you, but having another problem, can i add a default image by adding it to the project folder some how.... if can, can you let me know how..?

Comment: You could call ´standardImage.Save(@"YOUR_DESIRED_FILEPATH");´

Comment: how to add it, i mean, computer to computer it's gonna chage...so how to keep it un change

Comment: Will this be a web application?

Comment: Nope, desktop one,I've solve the problem now. I use resurce files with Image to binary converstion with if else.done.... Thank you guys